# Transactional emails: centering an image

Tags: magento-1.7, email, css, html, transactional-mail

I am trying to center an image within my transactional e-mail in Magento 1.7.

To do so, I am using the editor under `System -> Transactional Emails -> MyTemplate` and inserting the style for the html with the tag style. I tried different ways but none of them is centering my image. Here's the piece of code:

```
<table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
   <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
   <tr>
       <td valign="top">
           <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logoQM.png" _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="text-align: center; margin-bottom:10px;" border="0" height="65px"/></a>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

How should I do for my image to be centered? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just add `text-align: center` property to `td` or `tr` or `table` or add `display: block` to `a` tag like below.

```
<table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
   <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
   <tr>
       <td valign="top">
           <a href="{{store url=""}}"  style="display: block; text-align: center">
           <img src="{{skin url='images/logoQM.png' _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="text-align: center; margin-bottom:10px;" border="0" height="65px"/>
           </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**[*DEMO*](https://jsfiddle.net/pq1d5ozp/)**